# How to compress multi-identical conditions in a statement using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Here is what I did:

```
output = "xyz"
result = false

unless output == "" || output.nil? || output == "{}" || result == true
  puts 'execute this command'
end
```

What could be the simplest format to shrink the above statement, if there is a similar `||` conditions in Ruby

Comment: Are you comparing output to `{}` or to `"{}"` (string representation of an empty hash)?.

Comment: it is directly "{}" that I used to get from the api response body; so, it is "{}" . :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In versions of Ruby 2.5 and above you can use [`#any?`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Enumerable/any%3F) this way:

```
['', nil, '{}'].any?(output) || result

p ['', nil, '{}'].any?('')   # true
p ['', nil, '{}'].any?(nil)  # true
p ['', nil, '{}'].any?('{}') # true
```

Otherwise, you can use a block

```
['', nil, '{}'].any? { |e| e == output }
```

Comment: Yes, the 4th condition is different

Comment: also, `['', nil, '{}'].any?(output) || result` didn't work. Found extra argument(s). Required 0. But, the block worked fine

Comment: Yes, this was [introduced in the version](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11286) 2.5.

Comment: I use ruby 2.6.3; maybe the first solution has issues?

Comment: cos, the block worked fine but not the first solution

Comment: Doesn't `any?` use case-equality? Similar to `grep`.

Comment: Tested with Ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18] and it worked.

Comment: here is how I see in my rubymine editor; https://i.imgur.com/FqXg12I.png

Comment: What does `RUBY_VERSION` return from RubyMine?

Comment: 2.6.3 https://i.imgur.com/RjOSi9T.png the same in external libraries as well

Comment: Well, I think this might be a new question. Probably you're not the only one with that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
unless ["", nil, "{}"].include?(output) || result
  puts 'execute this command'
end
```